# Rails - Suppress RoutingError 404 on server side for static content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static, rails-routing

I'm fairly new to Rails, and my problem is as follows:
I'm making a GET request to a remote website via my server and I dish up the response as HTML to my front-end.
Unfortunately, the HTML I'm parsing from the remote site has references to static files which is causing a ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "...")
How can I suppress these errors in my controller so that they don't appear in my browser console?
Code is as follows:

```
def get_page

    url = URI.parse('[website]')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }

    @result = res.body

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :text => @result }
    end
end
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out, but I'm not sure if it's a very elegant solution.
In my routes.rb I put the following line at the bottom of all defined routes:

```
get '*static'  => 'home#static_404'
```

I then put the following method in my "home controller":

```
  def static_404
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

Seems to work, but I don't like how Rails forces me to use ***[random_letters]** to define this error route.
 ***** doesn't seem to work by itself, but if I type in anything afterwards it does.